# BigQuery - BQ extract - Multiple empty file generation

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Im trying to export data from big query table to zip file in command line by using BQ extract. It generated multiple empty files (with header) , along with one file with correct data. Can someone please let me know , why empty files are generated.

Thanks

Comment: can you explain how does your table look like and would it be possible that the table is empty or selected partitions (if you used `table$partition` notation) are empty?

Comment: can you please share with us your export logic?

Comment: This behavior may be a bug, please organize your code to accept multiple extracted files and there can be arbitrary number of records in each file (empty is a case when number of records is zero).

Answer (score 1):

This is a BigQuery issue [already reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142979335). I suggest [starring the issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) and asking for an update on it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same empty files issue when using EXPORT DATA.

After doing a bit of R&D found the solution. Put `LIMIT xxx` in your `SELECT` SQL and it will do the trick.

You can find the count, and put that as `LIMIT` value.

```
SELECT ....

FROM ...

WHERE ...

LIMIT xxx
```